# How to install a specific version of openssl

Tags: upgrade, package-management, versions, openssl

I am running 12.04 but the question applies to all ubuntu versions.
Is there a package for a specific (actually I am only interested in the newest) version of openssl?
Although I have the latest security patches installed, I do not get an up-to-date version of openssl, only an "old" one with some security patches applied.

If there is no prebuilt version available, what would be the best approach?
Is it possible to download simply the newest version of openssl and build a regular package from that and install it?

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, at least in LTS releases, the upstream version numbers of many packages never change for a given release. There are very few exceptions, such as Firefox, and the kernel.

You have three options:

- Upgrade a release. Not really an option.
- Find a PPA you can trust.
- Compile from source. This is definitely a viable option, but the exact steps depend on the software in question (so you'd best consult the OpenSSL site for instructions).

Compiling from source can be helped along by using `apt`. To install the libraries needed to build OpenSSL, you can do:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep openssl
```

You can also get the source package from the Ubuntu repositories and modify it to use a different upstream source tarball.

To get the source package used by Ubuntu:

```
apt-get source openssl
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on how to modify the source package? Perhaps I will give this a try in a safe environment.